# make: *** No rule to make target 'mykernel.bin'. Stop

Tags: make, c++, assembly

I'm worrking on an OS but I'm getting this error with my makefile.win. Looks like the linker.ld output file doesn't match the naming convention of the file i'm making (mykernel.bin). Not sure if that's the reason for the error. This is built for 64-bit systems.

**Makefile.win**

```
ASPARAMS =
LDPARAMS = -melf_x86_64

objects = loader.o kernel.o

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(GPPPARAMS) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.s
    as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)

install: mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

**linker.ld**

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x100000;  /* Adjust the starting address for 64-bit */

    .text :
    {
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata)
    }

    .data :
    {
        start_ctors = .;
        KEEP(*( .init_array ))
        KEEP(*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY( .init_array.* )))
        end_ctors = .;

        *(.data)
    }

    .bss :
    {
        *(.bss)
    }

    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.fini_array*)
        *(.comment)
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
~/MyOS$ make mykernel.bin
make: *** No rule to make target 'mykernel.bin'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Since your makefile has a non-default name, you need to tell make about it i.e. `make -f Makefile.win mykernel.bin` I think?